# How to use IsPostBack in MVC-4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, postback

I want to don't bind my dropdown list if the form state is post back. As you can see in my code I have two forms and two submit buttons. I want to keep selected value of dropdownlist after I click second submit button.

```
   <form method="POST" action="@Url.Action("UserRoles", "PageUserRole")">
                <label>Kullanıcı Grubu</label>
                @Html.DropDownList("Id",  Utility.GetUserGroups(), "Kullanıcı Grubu Seçiniz.")
                &nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Listele" />
            </form>
```

....

```
<form method="POST" action="@Url.Action("EditUserRoles", "PageUserRole")">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            İşlem
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Yetki
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PageMenUsuserRoles.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Model.PageMenUsuserRoles[i].pagemenu.Name

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.Hidden("PageMenUsuserRoles[" + i + "].Id", Model.PageMenUsuserRoles[i].Id)
                                &nbsp; @Html.CheckBox("PageMenUsuserRoles[" + i + "].CanView", Model.PageMenUsuserRoles[i].CanView)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                    <tr>

                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="submit" value="Kaydet" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Comment: there is no ispostback in mvc

Comment: MVC has no notion of `IsPostBack` in the sense that Web Forms do.

Comment: Ok I understand there is no ispostback. But how can I keep selected value of my ddl?

Comment: just show your action also..

Comment: Use Dropdownlistfor method of HTML helper for more information visit this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/

Comment: You cant. If your not posting back the selected value (its not within he second form element), how can the server method possibly know what the user has selected in the browser. If you want to stay on the same page, you could post using AJAX.